# RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED - разное поведения на устройствах

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Есть Service, который должен запускаться после ребута телефона. Для этого я сдела ресивер  и дал ему в Манифесте необходимые условия (какие нашел).

Есть 3 телефона и на всех них АБСОЛЮТНО разное поведение.

**Redmi 4x** *Android 7.1.2*. просто не хочет работать.

**Lenova K5 Note**. *Android 5.1*. тут сервис запускается после ребута, ТОЛЬКО ЕСЛИ сервис работал ДО перезагрузки

**Samsung Galaxy S5** *Android 6.0.1*. тут вроде все хорошо. нет разницы "был запущен сервис до этого? нет?". после перезагрузки сервис будет запущен.

MyReceiver

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, MusicServ.class);
        context.startService(intentService);
    }
}
```

Манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service
    android:name=".MusicServ"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":MusicServ">

</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".MyReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:enabled="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Comment: вы констатируете АБСОЛЮТНО известные факты. Для Redmi установите разрешение вручную для вашего приложения.

Comment: @Style-7 какие факты я констатирую? я хочу понять "как сделать 100% запуск службы после перезагрузки"

Comment: Не думаю что это поможет, но [`permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms) внутри тега `receiver` лишний - так вы говорите системе, что этот ресивер может быть вызван только приложением имеющем такую привелегию. А зачем посылающему приложению иметь привелегию на приём своих же сообщений...

Comment: @woesss логично! исправил. но это, к сожалению, не решает проблему с разным поведением =(

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/271663/ - прочтите статейку для общего понимания, может что прояснится. Потому как не известно правильно и одинаково ли вы тестируете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению это давно известная проблема, многие производители Android устройств (наиболее часто китайские) модифицируют систему, так чтобы приложения по умолчанию не могли работать в фоне, пока пользователь явно их не запустит (прошивка останавливает службы приложений, и не шлет приложениям системные события через интенты). Galaxy S5 ведет себя корректно (как должен стоковый Android), а Redmi 4x и Lenovo K5 Note - нет. К сожалению сделать с этим ничего нельзя, кроме как обнаруживать производителя устройства и выводить пользователю диалог с предложением добавить приложение в "белый список". На Xiaomi (MIUI) например должно помочь добавление приложения в автозапуск, выставление контроля активности - без ограничений и закрепление приложения в списке недавних.

Comment: но это ведь все должен делать сам пользователь? или есть программный способ?

Comment: к сожалению, только сам пользователь

Answer (score 0):

Как пишется в [документации ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED):

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Так что, вполне понятно почему результат непредсказуем.

Comment: а сам код верный? остается только положиться на благосклонность системы к приложению?

Comment: Это всего-лишь означает, что бродкаст с таким экшн имеет право послать только система, а не любое приложение.